# R h2o connection (memory) issue

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, machine-learning, h2o

I am trying to run optimizing grid for 2 algorithms (`random forest` and `gbm`) for different parts of a data set, using `h2o`. My code looks like

```
for (...)
{
        read data

        # setup h2o cluster
        h2o <- h2o.init(ip = "localhost", port = 54321, nthreads = detectCores()-1)

        gbm.grid <- h2o.grid("gbm", grid_id = "gbm.grid", x = names(td.train.h2o)[!names(td.train.h2o)%like%segment_binary], y = segment_binary, 
                             seed = 42, distribution = "bernoulli",
                             training_frame = td.train.h2o, validation_frame = td.train.hyper.h2o,
                             hyper_params = hyper_params, search_criteria = search_criteria)

    # shutdown h2o
    h2o.shutdown(prompt = FALSE)

    # setup h2o cluster
    h2o <- h2o.init(ip = "localhost", port = 54321, nthreads = detectCores()-1)

    rf.grid <- h2o.grid("randomForest", grid_id = "rf.grid", x = names(td.train.h2o)[!names(td.train.h2o)%like%segment_binary], y = segment_binary, 
                        seed = 42, distribution = "bernoulli",
                        training_frame = td.train.h2o, validation_frame = td.train.hyper.h2o,
                        hyper_params = hyper_params, search_criteria = search_criteria)

    h2o.shutdown(prompt = FALSE)
}
```

The problem is that if i run the `for loop` in one go, i get the error

```
Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = urlSuffix,  : 
  Unexpected CURL error: Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused
```

P.S.: I am using the line

```
 # shutdown h2o
h2o.shutdown(prompt = FALSE)

# setup h2o cluster
h2o <- h2o.init(ip = "localhost", port = 54321, nthreads = detectCores()-1)
```

So that I "reset" the `h2o`, so that i do not run out of memory

I also read [R H2O - Memory management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703121/r-h2o-memory-management) but it is not clear to me how it works.

**UPDATE**

After following Matteusz comment, i `init` outside the `for loop` and inside of the `for loop` i use  `h2o.removeAll()`. So now my code looks like this

```
 h2o <- h2o.init(ip = "localhost", port = 54321, nthreads = detectCores()-1)
for(...)
{
read data

gbm.grid <- h2o.grid("gbm", grid_id = "gbm.grid", x = names(td.train.h2o)[!names(td.train.h2o)%like%segment_binary], y = segment_binary, 
                             seed = 42, distribution = "bernoulli",
                             training_frame = td.train.h2o, validation_frame = td.train.hyper.h2o,
                             hyper_params = hyper_params, search_criteria = search_criteria)

h2o.removeAll()

rf.grid <- h2o.grid("randomForest", grid_id = "rf.grid", x = names(td.train.h2o)[!names(td.train.h2o)%like%segment_binary], y = segment_binary, 
                        seed = 42, distribution = "bernoulli",
                        training_frame = td.train.h2o, validation_frame = td.train.hyper.h2o,
                        hyper_params = hyper_params, search_criteria = search_criteria)

h2o.removeAll() }
```

It seems to work, but now i get this error (?) in the `grid optimization` for `random forest`

[image]

Any ideas what this might be ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems quite wasteful, starting up h2o twice every iteration. If you just want to free up the memory you can use `h2o.removeAll()` instead.

As for the cause, `h2o.shutdown()` (any H2O shutdown) is not a synchronized operation and some cleanup can still occur after the function returns (for example handling of outstanding requests). You can check using `h2o.clusterIsUp()` whether the cluster is actually down before starting it again with `init`.

Comment: So i should put the `init` inside something like `while(h2o.clusterIsUp())` ?

Comment: you should first runt `while(h2o.clusterIsUp())` (preferably with a `sleep` inside the loop) and run `h2o.init` after that loop. But as I mentioned all of that is wasteful, you don't need to start/stop the nodes every time.

Comment: @quant `removeAll` will remove also all the data that you uploaded to H2O yet you're using `td.train.h2o` etc. in your random forest modeling. Either upload that data again or instead of `removeAll` just remove the things you don't need anymore (previous models etc).

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the error is that you are not changing the `grid_id` parameter in your loop.  My recommendation is to let H2O auto-generate a grid id by leaving it unspecified/NULL.  You can also create different grid ids (one for each dataset) manually, but it's not required.

You can only add new models to an existing grid (by re-using the same grid id) when you use the same training set.  When you put a grid search in a for loop over different datasets and keep the same grid id, it will throw an error because you are trying to append models trained on different datasets to the same grid.