# Python H2O Memory Management

Tags: python, memory-management, h2o

Similar to this question in R [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703121/r-h2o-memory-management), I get out of memory issues when running loops with grid search in H2O. In R, doing gc() during each loop did help. What is the proposed solution here?

Comment: Please update with a code example of how your loop is set up.

Comment: have you tried `h2o.remove_all()` or `h2o.remove(x)`

Comment: I don't think they'd want to use `h2o.remove_all()` because that will remove everything from the H2O cluster, including all data and models...

Comment: Also, we recommend using the [H2OGridSearch](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/grid-search.html) method instead of writing a loop (unless you have a specific reason to).

Comment: I am using H2OGridSearch but for different features, so I am using a loop over different transformations and features, saving the best model of grid search and repeating. I guess in this case `remove_all()` makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 7):

There appears to be no `h2o.gc()` function in the Python API. See "How can I debug memory issues?" in [the FAQ](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/faq/general-troubleshooting.html?highlight=garbage). You could POST that back-end command (`GarbageCollect`) directly using the REST API if you suspect the problem is the back-end holding on to memory that it no longer should be. Studying the detailed logs, might help confirm if that is the case.

Wrapping up the advice from the comments:

- Use `h2o.remove()` on H2O frames and models you no longer need, at the end of the loop.
- Use `h2o.removeAll()` if you do not need to keep anything around, and your loop will be re-loading all the data it needs.
- Use `H2OGridSearch` rather than your own loops and your own grid code.

I'd also add to be aware that cbind, rbind and any function that modifies an H2O frame will make a copy of the entire frame. Sometimes re-thinking the way you do your data munging steps can reduce the memory requirements.