# Memory leak with H20 in Python Web Application

Tags: python, pandas, h2o

My decision engine is built on the python-flask framework with uWSGI and Nginx.
As part of evaluating a user through an HTTP request, I run scorecards with h2o==3.20.0.7 to generate a score to make a decision on the user. Given below some clarity on how I'm using h2o in my app

```
h2o.init()  # initialize 

predictions = h2o.mojo_predict_pandas(features_df, MODEL_MOJO_ZIP_FILE_PATH, MODEL_GENMODEL_JAR_PATH)  # generate score
# features_df -> pandas DF
```

H2o details from app start

```
--------------------------  ----------------------------------------
H2O cluster uptime:         01 secs
H2O cluster timezone:       Etc/UTC
H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC
H2O cluster version:        3.20.0.7
H2O cluster version age:    1 year, 7 months and 10 days !!!
H2O cluster name:           H2O_from_python_unknownUser_t8cqu9
H2O cluster total nodes:    1
H2O cluster free memory:    1.656 Gb
H2O cluster total cores:    4
H2O cluster allowed cores:  4
H2O cluster status:         accepting new members, healthy
H2O connection url:         http://localhost:54321
H2O connection proxy:
H2O internal security:      False
H2O API Extensions:         XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, Core V4
--------------------------  ----------------------------------------
```

Both H2o (running as a separate service) and the flask app are running in the same server (3 - 8 servers under a load balancer).

Sometimes the memory usage is steadily increasing and throwing `Cannot allocate memory`

while computing the scorecards. Then it is settling automatically by itself after sometimes. The scorecard runs along with the other rules (sequential run) under an HTTP request but the error is reporting only while computing scorecards. Assuming, it requires more memory as it involves with h2o. The traffic looks to be the same across this cycle. So I hope this is not due to the high traffic.

As per my investigation, some memory is hanging somewhere and it is not releasing.

**I did the following workarounds** to release the hanged memory and reduce the impact

**1** GC in h2o from python

https://aichamp.wordpress.com/2016/11/10/calling-h2o-garbage-collect-from-python

[Python H2O Memory Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45435739/python-h2o-memory-management)

- Not experienced a positive impact.

**2** Scheduled service restart - Gracefully replacing the old servers with new servers.

- Experienced a positive impact. 60-70% of the errors are gone.

I would like to understand what is happening internally and introduce a proper fix rather than a workaround. Help would be highly appreciated.

For your information,

**I haven't tried**

**1** updating H2o cluster to a new version as the current version is too old (1 year, 7 months and 11 days) - Agree that it is better to use the latest version but no guarantee that the same will not happen again and the effort required is also more in terms of validating the score, result, etc

**2** I haven't limited the memory usage of H2o by using `min_mem_size` as I don't want the scorecard evaluation to fail.

and

**I'm planning to**

**1** add a memory profiler to easily understand the memory utilization of each piece/process related to my app

**edit**

**2** separate out h2o from the flask app and host it in different servers so that scaling is easy.
- still, the same issue is possible.

- I go through some memory profiler but still couldn't finalize one which is best for my current situation. I would like to get a suggestion on this as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The approach you describe is different from what I would recommend.

For simplicity's sake (ignoring multiple servers and load balancing) I am going to draw your setup's architecture diagram like this:

```
[Client HTTP program] -> [python flask app] -> [java scoring backend]
```

This high-level architecture is fine, but you've gone about implementing the java scoring layer part in what I will say is the most difficult way possible instead of the intended way.

The intended way is to use only the MOJO and the lightweight MOJO runtime.  One straightforward way to do that is to wrap the MOJO in a very simple minimal web service.

Here are links to the javadoc for the MOJO:

- http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/overview-summary.html#whatisamojo

and a github repo demonstrating how to use a MOJO in a simple Java servlet container:

- https://github.com/h2oai/app-mojo-servlet

Also, here is an older github repo you might find useful that uses the POJO instead of the MOJO.  The MOJO is better.  Use the MOJO and not the POJO, but you may find reading the documentation in this repo helpful:

- https://github.com/h2oai/app-consumer-loan

Note if you do things this way you can still scale/load balance the [python flask app] and [java scoring backend] services separately if you want, although my expectation would be the java will be substantially faster than the python, so it might be easier just to scale the python and java together in groups of two, and have the python make requests to a local java.

---

OK, now that I've talked about the best practice way, let me point out some issues I can spot in what you are doing now (the difficult way).

1. You didn't mention whether you are scoring one row at a time or doing batch scoring.  Using the full H2O-3 server itself for scoring is much better suited for batch scoring and horrendously inefficient for scoring one row at a time.  The parsing process is heavyweight and the scoring process is heavyweight for one row at a time.  This will impact latency.
2. While you can read in the MOJO object itself to a full H2O-3 server process and use it for batch scoring, doing this in a real-time HTTP workflow was never the intent.  (Interestingly, support for doing this wasn't even possible for about the first 5 years of H2O-3's existence.)
3. There are definitely memory leaks if you don't clean up after yourself.

   Running the H2O-3 server process as a long-running service for scoring is not recommended.  But if you really want to do it, take these steps:

   - The in-memory objects need to be cleaned out.  You can find them with the h2o.ls() and remove them with the h2o.rm() calls in the R/python client APIs.  Both the datasets and the scores would need to be cleaned up.  You probably don't want to remove the model itself, though.
   - I don't expect you need to manually trigger garbage collections in the Java process, but you can if you want to.  Personally, I only do that when I have turned on Java flags like -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps so I can see the effect of the compaction on how much free heap memory remains after a Full GC.  I do this so I can see whether objects are really being retained, so I can confirm they are getting cleared out.  I like to give those logs to http://gceasy.io and visualize them.
   - Do monitor the logs to see the free heap remaining after a Full GC.
   - Even if you are doing the right stuff in terms of cleaning up memory, give the H2O-3 server process lots of memory.  I wouldn't even run it on my laptop with a smaller -Xmx than 5G.  As such, I would characterize the original poster's Java heap as severely under-provisioned (`H2O cluster free memory: 1.656 Gb`).
   - If you see the free heap remaining after Full GC creeping up, restart the Java process, since this is not the standard use case and not something that gets thoroughly tested.  The H2O-3 clusters are thought of by the development team as more as short-to-medium lifetime services (hours/days) than long-running services (months+, e.g. nginx/apache).

---

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions and advice. Missed to mention under "I'm planning to" section, but I was already thinking to separate out h2o from the flask app and host it in different servers. But no guarantee that this issue will not come again. I'm more interested and looking forward to understand the reason for the memory leakage. I tried GC manually in h2o as I mentoined above.  But no use. Then what is causing this? I don't see anything with h2o.ls() before or after GC (h2o.api(“POST /3/GarbageCollect”); h2o.remove_all())

Comment: I hope I'm scoring one row at a time -> for 1 user, 2 or 3 types of score-generation (rules) in one HTTP request. Additional to this, 10 + other rules are running. tat is ~10s